# Ordering neighbors in terms of 'weight' when finding similar nodes using embeddings

Tags: python, networkx, embedding, cosine-similarity

I have a series of triplets like:

```
[Patient1, affected, disease1],
[Patient1, affected, disease2],
[Patient1, affected, disease5],
[Patient2, affected, disease2],
[Patient1, affected, disease4]
...
```

I have imported this data into the python graph library networkx (Digraph() object), from there I applied the Node2Vec() algorithm to extract the node embeddings for all 'patients' and running cosine similarity on the embeddings I get the most similar patients given a specific patient.
Up until here everything is working, however I would like to know for each similar patient which neighbors add more 'weight' or 'value' towards that similarity score.
In other words, if I have a target patient as:

```
patient20 with neighbors [disease1, disease20, disease24, disease40]
```

and my most similar patient to this patient20 is:

```
patient34 with neighbors [disease4, disease6, disease24]
```

I would like to retrieve the neighbors of this similar patient in order of importance, in this case it would look something like this:

```
patient34 with neighbors [disease24, disease4, disease6]
```

Since disease24 is present in both it is safe to assume it was the biggest contributor for this patient being the most similar to the patient20 provided.

How could this be done? an approach using networkx is preferred but not required.